# crash function "g_assertion_message_expr.cold" killed gnome-control-center - no internet/what to do?

Tags: fedora, wifi

**Context**

Since yesterday, I have no working Internet connection on my Fedora 37 system.
I tried different Wifi-Connections and LAN - they are recognized and the Laptop can receive and send signals.

**Problem Reporting**

I have a Report for an Application Crash, saying "Wi-Fi quit unexpectedly":

> reason: gnome-control-center killed by SIGABRT 
> crash_function: g_assertion_message_expr.cold 
> cmdline: gonme-control-center wifi 
> executable: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center 
> package: gnome-control-center-43.1-1.fc37 
> component: gnome-control-center 
> pid: 4822 
> ... 
> type/analyzer: CCpp/abrt-journal-core 
> pkg_fingerprint: F55A D3FB 5323 552A 
> ... 
> kernel: 6.0.11-300.fc37.x86_64 
> ... 
> abrt_version: 2.15.1 
> ...

Thanks to a comment, i looked at what shows up with `journalctl -b`.
Since I don't really know what to look for, I made some screenshots [(link to upload...)](https://postimg.cc/gallery/gRF6hyz) of error-messages and logs with anything "Network" of "Wifi" in it.

**And now?**

I am a greenhorn on Linux. Some internet research didn't help much (there seems to have been [a similar bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1786496) - but that was a year ago and the fixes to that should be implemented on my version of Fedora...)

Therefore, my question is twofold:

- How do I deal with such an error message? Where/how can I learn how to tackle such a problem?
- and, obviously, any hints on how I could get my internet-connection running again?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please inspect the output of `journalctl -.b`: It's a lot of information, but try to find out what happened before that error was triggered, and include some of the messages you think they are relevant to your question. It will help others to understand what's going on.

Comment: @U.Windl I looked through some 20k lines, made some [Screenshots](https://postimg.cc/gallery/gRF6hyz) and updatet the questions accordingly. I hope I didn't skip the important stuff...

Comment: Add relevant screenshots to your question ("edit") instead of providing them elsewhere. Also to me it looks a bit as if your software doesn't like your hardware (e.g. bluetooth).